# Translate object position when clicking

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm searching for the method to move my 3D object (.gltf format) to an alternate position when the box is checked as well as moving back to the initial position when the box is unchecked. However, I'm not sure what is the proper way of doing this.
I created an object transition function but the object doesn't seem to move according to the checkbox.

here's my function code

```
function zoom() {
                    var move = document.getElementById('controllr');
                    if (move.checked) {
                        model2.position.set(0, 50, 0);
                    } else {
                        model2.position.set(0, 25, 0);
                    }
                }
```

Thank you in advance for any solution.

I still can not figure out how to achieve my intention so I created a new post with full code here.

[Moving object on checkbox event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70084942/moving-object-on-checkbox-event)

Comment: Why are you asking Java experts to review this question?

Comment: I was expecting three.js experts to review my question. Sorry if I have been mistaken about the tag.

Comment: Yes, you've flagged them using the appropriate tag, but *again* why are you tagging this a ***Java*** question? As I understand it, Three.js is a *JavaScript* library, not a *Java* library, two completely different languages. You show no Java code in your question.

Comment: I was curious if there is Java relevance that I am unaware of here

Comment: I had removed it, sorry again

Comment: Store the position(s) as a Vector3 in model2.userData. It is more natural to maintain than a static value within a function. So with multiple models you will not overwrite unique position settings.

Comment: @PartialFlavor_55KP Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

When are you actually calling the zoom function? If you put this code inside an event listener, it should work.

```
var move = document.getElementById('controllr');
move.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  if (e.currentTarget.checked) {
    model2.position.set(0, 50, 0);
  } else {
    model2.position.set(0, 25, 0);
  }
}
```